# Integrating Windows Identity Foundation with NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, wif

Has anyone successfully integrated NServiceBus with WIF for message authentication/authorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done by serializing and deserializing claims information through the headers of NServiceBus messages and then checking them in a message handler specified to run before all others, which will call Bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers() accordingly.